# Is the set of non-decreasing functions from $[0,1]$ to a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ compact and first countable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $Y$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $X\subseteq Y^{[0, 1]}$ be the set of non-decreasing functions from $[0,1]$ to $Y$, where $Y^{[0,1]}$ has product topology. Is $X$ compact and first-countable?

I know this is the case when $Y=[0,1]$, as then $X$ is a Helly space. But I don't know if this generalizes. If it does not, what additional assumptions on $Y$ would be required to make this true?

Comment: What topology on $X$ are you taking?

Comment: Topology of point-wise convergence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y$ is compact, so it is contained in $[-R, R]$ for some $R > 0$. It is then clear that $X$ is a closed subset of the space of non-decreasing functions from $[0, 1]$ to $[-R, R]$. The latter space is clearly homeomorphic to the Helly space, so compact and first-countable. As $X$ is a closed subspace, it must be compact and first-countable as well.

Comment: Maybe less confusing, if $X_0\subseteq [-R, R]^{[0, 1]}$ is the copy of Helly space, then $X = X_0\cap Y^{[0, 1]}$, where $Y^{[0, 1]}$ is a closed subset of $[-R, R]^{[0, 1]}$, so $X$ is closed in $X_0$